# why cant i change the position of the panel inside a frame?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to create a GUI with a couple of buttons and a drawing area.
it seems to be working except the drawing area is very small and not in the right location.
here is my code:

```
public class ssGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected JButton b1, bConnect, bDisconnect, b2;
protected JPanel canvas;

public ssGUI() {
    // run button
    b1 = new JButton("do something");
    b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
    b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b1.setEnabled(false);
    // connect button
    bConnect = new JButton("Connect");
    bConnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bConnect.addActionListener(this);
    bConnect.setEnabled(true);
    // disconnect button
    bDisconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    bDisconnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    bDisconnect.addActionListener(this);
    bDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
    // clean nmea data button
    b2 = new JButton("do something else");
    b2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b2.setEnabled(false);
    // drawing panel
    canvas = new JPanel();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.white);

    add(b1); add(bConnect); add(bDisconnect); add(b2); add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Range Adjustment GUI");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ssGUI newContentPane = new ssGUI();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocation(500, 500);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}}
```

this is how my GUI looks like:

[image]

as you can see, the "canvas" is very small and at the side of the buttons.
i need it to be placed underneath them and fill frame area.
can anyone help me to resolve that problem?
thank you for your help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: `add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);` is correct but what about other component ? you didn't specify location for them ? one simple solution is add another panel to borderlayout.north and add buttons to it.

Comment: i have changes the adding part to: `add(b1, BorderLayout.LINE_START); add(bConnect, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); add(bDisconnect, BorderLayout.CENTER); add(b2, BorderLayout.LINE_END); add(canvas, BorderLayout.PAGE_END)` but it does not do any thing. the GUI still looks the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set your main panel's layout to `BorderLayout`.
2. Create a panel just for your buttons and add this panel to your main panel's `NORTH` position.

Here is a working example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ssGUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected JButton b1, bConnect, bDisconnect, b2;
    protected JPanel canvas;

    public ssGUI() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // run button
        b1 = new JButton("do something");
        b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
        b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
        b1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b1.setEnabled(false);
        // connect button
        bConnect = new JButton("Connect");
        bConnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        bConnect.addActionListener(this);
        bConnect.setEnabled(true);
        // disconnect button
        bDisconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
        bDisconnect.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        bDisconnect.addActionListener(this);
        bDisconnect.setEnabled(false);
        // clean nmea data button
        b2 = new JButton("do something else");
        b2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b2.setEnabled(false);
        // drawing panel
        canvas = new JPanel();
        canvas.setBackground(Color.white);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(b1);
        topPanel.add(bConnect);
        topPanel.add(bDisconnect);
        topPanel.add(b2);
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Range Adjustment GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ssGUI newContentPane = new ssGUI();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another problem with the layouts.

JPanel has a default layout and I don't see you setting the layout for `ssGUI` class. Hence the default layout (FlowLayout) will be used.

All components added to `ssGUI` will be arranged in a linear fashion in a row for as much as it can hold. When your component exceed the width, it will be placed to the next row.

You can consider using a layout for your main panel `ssGUI`. A [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will probably give you what you want.

Comment: where do i declare this layout?

Comment: You may do it in the constructor of `ssGUI` e.g. `this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`

Comment: now i am having error saying: `cannot add to layout: constraints must be a GridBagConstraint`.  do i have to change my `add()` method?

Comment: @DanyLavrov GridBagLayout is one of the most flexible layout, unfortunately it is also one of the more complicated ones. You need to set the constraints for it. Do take a look at the link in my solution.

Comment: i Have read it. for each component i have created the following: `GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
     c.gridx = 0; c.gridy = 0;
     add(b1, c);` ofcourse i have changed the gridx and gridy for each one.  still getting the same error